# Update list of tables from one table to another with foreign key constraints

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to create dynamic SQL to update tables from a production db to a lower environment where foreign constraints are involved?  Right now I have the following but I am running into the issue of the foreign keys being different across environments:

```
DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('some_table')
INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('some_table2')

DECLARE @value VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @insert_cmd varchar(MAX), @del_cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Value FROM @MyList
OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
        IF OBJECT_ID('Staging.dbo.'+@value) IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN 
        SET @del_cmd = N'DROP TABLE Staging.dbo.'+@value+';'; 
        --EXEC sp_executesql @del_cmd; 
        print @del_cmd
           END
        SET @insert_cmd = 'select * into Staging.dbo.'+@value+' from prod.dbo.'+@value+';'
        --EXEC (@insert_cmd)
        print @insert_cmd

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: Is there a way? Yes, of course. Is it difficult and perhaps impossible based on your DDL? Perhaps. You must translate your IDs between the 2 databases based on the natural keys. If you have not defined natural keys, then it is logically impossible though you might be able to force a translation based on various assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: First copy the schema, then disable all the constraints and copy the data afterwards. Enable constraints after data copy completes.

```
    DECLARE @MyList TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(50))
    INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('some_table')
    INSERT INTO @MyList VALUES ('some_table2')

    DECLARE @value VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @insert_cmd varchar(MAX), @del_cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT Value FROM @MyList
    OPEN db_cursor   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value   

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
    BEGIN   
            IF OBJECT_ID('Staging.dbo.'+@value) IS NOT NULL 
            BEGIN 
            SET @del_cmd = N'DROP TABLE Staging.dbo.'+@value+';'; 
            --EXEC sp_executesql @del_cmd; 
            print @del_cmd
               END
            SET @insert_cmd = 'select * into Staging.dbo.'+@value+' from prod.dbo.'+@value+' where 1<>1;
            ALTER TABLE Staging.dbo.'+@value+' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;
            insert into Staging.dbo.'+@value+' select * from prod.dbo.'+@value+';
            ALTER TABLE Staging.dbo.'+@value+' CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;'


            --EXEC (@insert_cmd)
            print @insert_cmd

           FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @value   
    END   

    CLOSE db_cursor   
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```